# User Levels in SQL

Tags: php, mysql

Okay, so I have created a user table inside of my database to hold all the users data

```
CREATE TABLE `user` (
`id` INT NOT NULL auto_increment,
`username` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL default '',
`nicename` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL default '',
`email` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL default '',
`password` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL default '',
`permissions` INT NOT NULL default '1',
UNIQUE KEY `user_n` (`username`),
UNIQUE KEY `user_e` (`email`),
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

I want the permissions field to dictate what users can and cannot see. IE. The permissions for the ACP would require a permissions level of 3 whereas 1 is a registered user and 0 is a guest visiting the site. How could I get a page to block itself depending upon a users permission level? Thanks in advance.
Using MySQL/PHP

Comment: The query on the page that displays the information query needs to take the user's level as a parameter. Post the structure of the table the information is on and I'll give you an example.

Comment: I haven't actually created the table with the information yet; still in the process of developing all of that; Was looking to make it something along the lines of `CREATE TABLE `pages` (`id` INT NOT NULL auto_increment, `page_name` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL default '', `title` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL default '', `header` VARCHAR(50) '', `content` LONGTEXT NOT NULL default '', PRIMARY KEY (`id`)); ` So if you have any ideas that would be awesome. Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have the user login , fetch his permissions from table and depending upon the permission redirect him/her to appropriate page e.g.

```
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:dbname=dbname;host=hostname", "username", "password" );
$result = $dbh->prepare("select check_user_exists(?) as retval");
$result->bindParam(1, $value, PDO::PARAM_STR, 2);
$result->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, 'stdClass');
$result->execute(); 
switch($result) {
 case 1 : $header('Location:x.php');
 case 2 : $header('Location:y.php');
 case 3 : $header('Location:z.php'); 
 default 'no suitable page found');
 break;
}
```

Comment: Me and Headers look as if they might be a good thing to start learning. Never got along to well, but shows that they could be quite effective. I usually only use them in a need basis, but I may have to reflect on them a little bit more. Also; I'm not sure what the $dbh is; is that a global variable or one that I would have to manually set inside of my config file?

Comment: just edited my answer to give you an idea of dbh , actually dbh ia  variable of PDO type more on PDO can be read at http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Comment: I'll take a look; brand new system to me, so hopefully I can grasp it relatively quickly.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use MySQL [user-account-management](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/user-account-management.html) You can use switch case

```
$permissions = $_GET["permissions"];//Or Post from html page
switch ($permissions)
{
case 1:
  //Level 1 code
  break;
case 2:
  //level 2 code
 break;
case 3:
 //level 3 code
  break;
default:
  //default code
```

}

Comment: This looks fairly simple and effective at the same time. I'll have to look into it more as I've never seen anything like it, but I think it understands. Essentially there would be the code of the webpage under the case then it would break. A level 1 user would see level 1 code but not two or three. Now would 0 work as a permission level for someone not registered? IE `$permissions = $GET["permissions"]; with ($permissions) { case 0: <?php include 'body_content_guest.php'; ?> break; case 2:<?php include 'body_content_user.php'; ?> break; case 3:<?php include 'body_content_admin.php'; ?> }`

Comment: The username & password will also be passed from the calling page and used to validate the password There are plenty of scripts for login using PHP/MySQL which you can add to. Also as it is a new application you should use PDO instead of mysql_* functions for tutorial see http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/

Comment: In the mean time while I work on getting PDO going on my site; Is there anyways to use the $_GET command to pull information from the SQL database rather then form data?